# Can The Basement Collection be played with a controller?

Tags: the-basement-collection

After all the hubbub about Super Meat Boy playing best with a controller, I don't think I can do it at all with a keyboard.  Does this game *(or at least, the Meat Boy portion of it)* support a controller?

Comment: I Know [Super Meat Boy](http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj186/EmilHansen/SuperMeatBoy.png) does, the link is a screen dump of the start up screen. I also completed it with my Gamepad

Comment: Super Meat Boy is XNA Based so it pretty much natively supports controllers (unless you use one of the few non direct/x-input controllers).  The game in the basement collection is, I beleive, "Meat Boy" (not super).

Answer (score 3):

As far as the feature list on Steam is concerned, **no**.  You can use alternative programs that have already been stated: Joy2key and Xpadder in order to wrap your controller inputs and send them as raw keys to the games in question.

Answer (score -1):

No. The games on Basement Collection are all flash games, therefore, they don't support controllers. As an alternative, you can use some software to map specific keys to your joystick... search for Joy2key or Xpadder.

Comment: *"..are all flash games, therefore, they don't support controllers"* - Er, -1, this is false information.  Flash has [an API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/GameInput.html) for accessing controllers.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Actually, I'm pretty sure that class is only available in AIR apps (which The Basement Collection is not targeted as).

Comment: Thanks for the informations! I didn't know about this API.